# What am I doing wrong with Lambda

Tags: c++

I have a problem. First, consider this 2D vector called explored:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>explored;
```

Now, consider, that I have a function, to which I passed this vector and two integers, called row and col:

```
bool check(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const explored, int row, int col);
```

Now, I want to implement the std::find for this 2D vector and check whether its vectors (which all have 2 integer values by the way) are equal to the row and col:

```
explored[n][0] == row && explored[n][1] == col;
```

So, I wrote this:

```
if(std::find(explored.begin(), explored.end(), [row,col](vector<int> a, int row, int col){ return a[0] == row && a[1] == col;}) == explored.end()){
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? My compiler (which is Xcode GNU) gives this error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >' and 'const (lambda at /Users/abylikhsanov/CLionProjects/bfs/main.cpp:8:60)')
        if (*__first == __value_)
```

Comment: You need `std::find_if`, not `std::find` :)

Comment: But isn't if find == end the same as find_if?

Comment: Declaration of find and find_if is different: find searches for value with == operator, find_if searches for predicat calling p() where p is function, or some callable object. By the way: you should declare const vector& by reference in your check function declaration to avoid copying.

Comment: No, checking for the end is what `std::any_of` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a predicate to the find utility, `std::find_if` is what you are looking for.
Moreover, note that the signature of the predicate is:

```
 bool pred(const Type &a);
```

Therefore, it turns your example to something like this:

```
if(std::find_if(explored.begin(), explored.end(), [row,col](const vector<int> &a){ return a[0] == row && a[1] == col;}) == explored.end()){
    return true;
}
```

I've used also a const reference as an argument for the lambda, so as to avoid copying the vectors back and forth each and every time your function is invoked.